# Renege a SE offer close to the start date

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I got an offer from Amazon for a new grad SE role in Vancouver. I accepted the offer at the beginning of May. Now, I am almost done with the onboarding process. Amazon has completed my background check and wired a 6K relocation reimbursement for moving to Vancouver. I am still waiting to meet my supervisor. My starting date is the beginning of August, so about 1 month away.

Just today, Google recruiter contacted me and would like to begin the hiring process for a new grad SE role at Google in the US. Let's assume the Google hiring process will take 2-3 weeks, and I get an offer in mid July. I really value Google US >>> Amazon Canada, because of mainly the pay and also reputation.

Do you think it is still possible to renege Amazon at that time considering it will be only 2-3 weeks before my start date, and assuming I have met with my supervisor? Is it fine for doing so? Any risks involved with reneging this close to the start date?

Comment: Make sure to take a look at the cost of living difference especially if the Google job is in Silicon Valley.

Comment: People decry how awful it is that a company will rescind an offer to a candidate just prior to the start date, and no one really seems to have a problem with that behavior going in the other direction.

Comment: @Chen, What do you think about **work-life balance** between Amazon vs Google ? Which company is better when it comes to  work-life balance ?

Comment: It is tough to say, I have interned with Google before but never worked at Amazon. For me personally, they are all the same to me. A full-time SE job is a full-time SE job. Only salary and career growth matter in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an offer in your hands, Google *might* offer you a position - but it's better to have an apple in your hands than hanging in the tree. Risks are that you end up having no offer in case Google isn't interested and Amazon puts you on a no-hire list.

One way of pulling this through thou is to continue the hiring process with Google and once you have an offer you could resign in your probation period and start your new gig.

Be aware that you most likely need to reimburse them their reallocation-funds and that they won't consider you for hiring anymore in the future. The job-hopping stigma wouldn't apply here that much, since you could always say that the gig at Amazon wasn't a perfect fit for you.

Make sure you don't pull off such stunts too often as it will show up in your emplyoment history when checked and you might come across as cherry picker which leaves any company as soon something better comes around (labeled as high flight risk).

Addition:

A probation-period is for both parties, the employer and the employee, to find out if things are working out the way they were intended to (cultural fit within the organisation, work-load, commitment of the employee etc, etc). That means it is completely fine if one party decides to end the agreement within the probation-period. One thing to keep in mind is that it will reflect poorly on you when you quit during your probation-period too often - but once can be seen as normal.

Comment: @iLuvLogic, makes sense. Is it okay to leave during the probation period?

Comment: @Chen I wrote an addition to my answer.

Comment: It is Ok to leave during the probation period. I'd check my contract very carefully to see what it says about relocation cost which is not insignificant.

Comment: As a person from Google a few more points:

1. "Let's assume the Google hiring process will take 2-3 weeks" - it doesn't. It usually takes months.

2. Google (and any other large tech company) is hiring pretty much non-stop, especially for generic SWE positions. Tell your Google contact that you'd be in position to interview in 6-12 months and they'll get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

> Any risks involved with reneging this close to the start date?

In my experience when they give you money in advance, or money during the probation period, they will also have paperwork included that states if it has to be paid back, and if there is a schedule where if you stay x months you have to repay half, if you stay y months you have to pay nothing. Check all the documents you received from the company.   That is your biggest risk corporate wise.

Probation is a time for both sides to evaluate each other, some percentage of new hires leave during probation. You have a complexity because one job is in Canada and the other is in the United States. So one or both of these positions requires a visa. Those take time. So if the first job required a visa, make sure the processing of the paperwork didn't also obligate you to some monetary amount if you leave early. If the second job requires a visa, remember those can take time.

If the plan is to move to Vancouver, and quit when the US job is ready, make sure that you haven't obligated yourself to a 12 month lease that will cost thousands to break. Also that double move will be more expensive than a single move.

Remember until the second job has given you a job offer that has no conditions you can't know if the 2nd job will actually happen. By conditions I mean background check, drug check, visa paperwork. These can take time. They can take longer then anybody estimates.

> Do you think it is still possible to renege Amazon at that time
> considering it will be only 2-3 weeks before my start date, and
> assuming I have met with my supervisor? Is it fine for doing so?

Rejecting the first job before starting happens all the time. Let them know as soon as you can, so they can adjust their plans. Keep in mind they might never offer you a job again.